# Java uncatchable ClassNotFoundException when using java.awt.Clipboard

Tags: java, exception, awt, classnotfoundexception

I get the following exception when running this code

```
private static String getClipboard() {
        try {

            return (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);

        } catch (IOException | UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
            System.exit(-1);
            return "";
        }
    }
```

```
Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/intellij/codeInsight/editorActions/FoldingData"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData
Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/intellij/codeInsight/editorActions/FoldingData"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData
Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/intellij/openapi/editor/impl/EditorCopyPasteHelperImpl$CopyPasteOptionsTransferableData"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-serialized-object; class=com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorCopyPasteHelperImpl$CopyPasteOptionsTransferableData
Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/intellij/openapi/editor/impl/EditorCopyPasteHelperImpl$CopyPasteOptionsTransferableData"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-serialized-object; class=com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorCopyPasteHelperImpl$CopyPasteOptionsTransferableData
```

I haven't found a clear solution to completely solve this.
Someone suggested to print every error in a file,
but this wouldn't solve the problem and would "hide" it instead.
Any idea on how to prevent that exception from happening?

Comment: *but this wouldn't solve the problem and would "hide" it instead.* You couldn't hide it *more* than you are doing at the moment (swallowing the exception and terminating your app). I suppose you could argue that *not* terminating would be hiding it more. What you should be doing is logging exceptions, or a least printing the stack trace

Comment: What makes this "uncatchable"? Are you trying to deal with the exception? Or are you asking to improve your `try` block since you are asking '_how to prevent that exception from happening_'?

Comment: Edit your question and show the complete stack trace for at least one of those exceptions.  The code you have shown us does not construct any DataFlavors, much less an application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref or application/x-java-serialized-object DataFlavor.

Answer (score 1):

You should always check what the available clipboard formats are before accessing, as  it may not always contain a `String`. You can do this with:

```
if (clipboard.isDataFlavorAvailable(DataFlavor.stringFlavor))
...
```

This will print what formats are available:

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

System.out.println("hasString "+clipboard.isDataFlavorAvailable(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
for(var f : clipboard.getAvailableDataFlavors())
{
    System.out.println(f);
}
```

It is never a good plan to slip `System.exit()` into any handler - remove. In theory the clipboard could be changed by another app between checking so you need your exception handler to return "" or throw it as your own exception type.

```
static String getClipboard() {
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    try {
        // Note that it is still possible for another app to modify clipboard
        // between "if" and "return", so this could still fail:
        if(clipboard.isDataFlavorAvailable(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
            return (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // or rethrow as your own exception type
    }
    return "";
}
```